# Android studio - adding wrong permissions automatically in app

Tags: java, android, xml, permissions, manifest

I have an app and the permissions (that are given by me) in the app are these

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I had never given phone permissions `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` or `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` and if I try to search these two permissions they are not there.

`android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`

[image]

`android.permission.CALL_PHONE`

[image]

Everything is ok right? but once I run the app in my phone, It shows the permission.

[image]

My app don't need that permission, how do I remove it? please help me. Thank you.

Comment: probably one of the libraries you use is using this permission

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/605/why-do-so-many-applications-require-permission-to-read-the-phone-state-and-ident

Comment: So I have to remove it from `Gradle` (I mean the library)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your libraries use them, then they will be included automatically. Please find below code to disable.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

Please note that this may cause the libraries misbehave

Comment: How do I know which library using that permission?

Comment: You have to check the source code of the library. The code to disable can be included in your application Manifest

Comment: When you add a library to your gradle, you add a link to that library. Google the link, you will find out the source code